# JTable createAction response

Tags: java, jtable

I'm new with JTable, the table isn't refresh when I create a new entry but it does when I update o delete.
In the Servlet I create an arrayList for the newly create object (It's correctly inserted in the DB) so the resulting JSON is

```
{"Result":"OK","Records":[{"ID":123456,"Description":"New Object"}]}
```

Any idea of why the table doesn't refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be error in java script.

For example.Check your jtable field.This is example of java script code.

---

```
 fields: {

          customerid:{
                    title: 'No',
                    width: '4%',
                        key: true,
                        edit: false
                    },
          customername:{
                        title: 'Customer Name',
                        width: '25%',
                        edit: true
                    },
         }
```

---

Here is the server side jtable with Spring

```
            //Convert Java Object to Json               
            JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(showCoustomerList, new TypeToken<List<Customers>>() {}.getType());
            JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
            String listData=jsonArray.toString();               
            //Return Json in the format required by jTable plugin
            listData="{\"Result\":\"OK\",\"Records\":"+listData+"}";            
            response.getWriter().print(listData);
```